# django-import-exportのCSVインポートエラーがどこで発生しているのか知りたい。

Tags: python, django

お世話になります。

サッカーゲームの選手閲覧作成を目指して、作成を行っております。

現在、django-import-exportにてCSVインポートをする為に、
CSVの作成とadmin内容の設定を行なっております。

今回、django-import-exportを使用するにあたり、
下記文献を参考に、adminの内容を設定致しました。

参考文献
https://tech.fragment.co.jp/python/django/django-import-export/
https://qiita.com/d_kvn/items/463787f80ea906e955b1

恐らくForeignKeyとManyToManyのadminの記載の誤りが原因で、
下記エラーが発生しているかと思うのですが、
CSVのカラム項目の変更及びadminのカラム名称の変更を行なっても
同様のエラーが発生しているため、どの点でエラーが発生しているのか、
知れる方法があれば、ご教示頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

**エラー内容**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 676, in import_row
    diff = self.get_diff_class()(self, original, new)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.left = self._export_resource_fields(resource, instance)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 248, in _export_resource_fields
    return [resource.export_field(f, instance) if instance else "" for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 248, in <listcomp>
    return [resource.export_field(f, instance) if instance else "" for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 888, in export_field
    return field.export(obj)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 122, in export
    value = self.get_value(obj)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 87, in get_value
    value = getattr(value, attr, None)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 851, in __init__
    raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '   File "/Users/mm/e_football2022/django/e_football2022/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 519, in __repr__
    return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

**CSV内容**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**インポート画面**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**models.py**

```
class RarityCategory(models.Model):
  rarity = models.CharField('レアリティ',max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rarity)

class PositionCategory(models.Model):
  position = models.CharField('ポジショングループ',max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.position)

class ClubCategory(models.Model):
  clubname = models.CharField('クラブグループ',max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.clubname)

class LeagueCategory(models.Model):
  leaguename = models.CharField('リーググループ',max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.leaguename)

class PlayStyleCategory(models.Model):
  playstyle = models.CharField('プレースタイルグループ', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
        return str(self.playstyle)

class Skill(models.Model):
    player_skill = models.CharField('スキル名', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.player_skill)

class Player(models.Model):
    new_date_field = models.DateTimeField('リリース日', blank=True, null=True)
    initial = models.IntegerField('初期総合値', blank=True, null=True)
    maximum = models.IntegerField('最大総合値', blank=True, null=True)
    level = models.IntegerField('最大レベル', blank=True, null=True)
    player_name = models.CharField('選手名', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField('国名', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField('年齢', blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField('身長', blank=True, null=True)
    dominant_foot = models.CharField('利き足', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    player_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', verbose_name='プレイヤー画像', null=True, blank=True)
    position_group = models.ForeignKey(PositionCategory, verbose_name='ポジショングループ' ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    rarity_group = models.ForeignKey(RarityCategory, verbose_name='レアリティ' ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    club_group = models.ForeignKey(ClubCategory, verbose_name='クラブグループ' ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    league_group = models.ForeignKey(LeagueCategory, verbose_name='リーググループ' ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    playstyle_group = models.ForeignKey(PlayStyleCategory, verbose_name='プレースタイルグループ' ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, verbose_name='スキル' , blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name
```

**admin.py**

```
from import_export import fields, resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export.resources import ModelResource
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget, ManyToManyWidget
from import_export.fields import Field

class PositionCategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = PositionCategory

# Costモデルに統合する為にModelResourceを継承したクラスを作成
class ClubCategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = ClubCategory

class LeagueCategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = LeagueCategory

class RarityCategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = RarityCategory

# Shopモデルに統合する為にModelResourceを継承したクラスを作成
class PlayStyleCategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayStyleCategory

# Costモデルに統合する為にModelResourceを継承したクラスを作成
class SkillResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill

class PlayerResource(resources.ModelResource):
    position_group = Field(attribute='position_group', column_name='position_group_id', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(PositionCategory, 'id'))
    rarity_group = Field(attribute='rarity_group', column_name='rarity_group_id', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(RarityCategory, 'id'))
    club_group = Field(attribute='club_group', column_name='club_group_id', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(ClubCategory, 'id'))
    league_group = Field(attribute='league_group', column_name='league_group_id', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(LeagueCategory, 'id'))
    playstyle_group = Field(attribute='playstyle_group', column_name='playstyle_group_id', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(PlayStyleCategory, 'id'))
    skill = Field(attribute='skill', column_name='skill_id', widget=ManyToManyWidget(Skill, field='id'))
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        import_order = ('id', 'new_date_field', 'initial', 'maximum', 'level', 'player_name', 'country', 'age', 'height', 'dominant_foot', 'player_image', 'position_group', 'rarity_group', 'club_group', 'league_group', 'playstyle_group', 'skill')
        import_id_fields = ['id']

@admin.register(RarityCategory)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class RarityCategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'rarity')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = RarityCategoryResource


@admin.register(PositionCategory)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class PositionCategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'position')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = PositionCategoryResource


@admin.register(ClubCategory)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class ClubCategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'clubname')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = ClubCategoryResource

@admin.register(LeagueCategory)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class LeagueCategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'leaguename')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = LeagueCategoryResource


@admin.register(PlayStyleCategory)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class PlayStyleCategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'playstyle')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = PlayStyleCategoryResource


@admin.register(Skill)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class SkillAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'player_skill')

    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = SkillResource

@admin.register(Player)
# ImportExportModelAdminを継承したadminクラスを作成
class PlayerImportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=('id', 'new_date_field', 'initial', 'maximum', 'level', 'player_name', 'country', 'age', 'height', 'dominant_foot', 'player_image', 'position_group', 'rarity_group', 'club_group', 'league_group', 'playstyle_group', 'skill')
    filter_horizontal = ('skill',)
    # resource_classにModelResourceを継承したクラスを設定
    resource_class = PlayerResource

    def skill(self, row):
        return ','.join([x.player_skill for x in row.meta.all()])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現時点ではありますが、
ForeignKeyWidgetの設定を下記の内容に変更を行なうことで、
インポートすること自体は成功致しました。

```
class PlayerResource(resources.ModelResource):
position_group = Field(attribute='position_group', column_name='position_group_id',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(PositionCategory))
rarity_group = Field(attribute='rarity_group', column_name='rarity_group_id',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(RarityCategory))
club_group = Field(attribute='club_group', column_name='club_group_id',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(ClubCategory))
league_group = Field(attribute='league_group', column_name='league_group_id',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(LeagueCategory))
playstyle_group = Field(attribute='playstyle_group', column_name='playstyle_group_id',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(PlayStyleCategory))
skill = Field(attribute='skill', column_name='skill_id',widget=ManyToManyWidget(Skill))
class Meta:
    model = Player
    fields = ('id', 'new_date_field', 'initial', 'maximum', 'level', 'player_name', 'country', 'age', 'height', 'dominant_foot', 'player_image', 'position_group', 'rarity_group', 'club_group', 'league_group', 'playstyle_group', 'skill')
    import_id_fields = ['id']
```

但し、new_date_fieldとskillのManyToManyWidgetが取り込みができない状況です。
引き続き自己解決が出来るように取り組めればと思いますので、
一旦、こちらの質問はこの回答を持って、解決済みにしたいと思います。

また上記2点で解決出来ない点があれば、ご質問させて頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。